# Does Tool Expertise and Wonder Maker stack?

Tags: character-creation, optimization, stacking

I have a Rock Gnome Artificer, which grants Tool Expertise, but I want to take the Wonder Maker feat. Do you add +3 for proficiency, +3 because of Tool Expertise, and +3 because of Wonder Maker when doing a tinker's tools check?

**Tool Expertise**

Starting at 3rd level, your proficiency bonus is doubled for any ability check you make that uses your proficiency with a tool.

Starting at 6th level, your proficiency bonus is doubled for any ability check you make that uses your proficiency with a tool.

**Wonder Maker**

When you make a check using your proficiency with tinker’s tools, you add double your proficiency bonus to the check.

Comment: Hi Isabella, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and visit the [help] for more guidance. Unfortuantley, even though it's pretty clear you're asking about D&D 5e, we have a policy that says we aren't allowed to answer your question until _you explicitly tell us you're playing D&D 5e_. However, as soon as you can do that for us, we can answer your question. The best way to tell us is to add the [dnd-5e] tag to your question, but a comment or otherwise suits us as well, so long as it comes from you.

Comment: If this is D&D 5e, then it is answered here: [Do features that allow you to add twice your proficiency bonus, under some other name, stack with Expertise?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135832/do-features-that-allow-you-to-add-twice-your-proficiency-bonus-under-some-other)